# How to store the username in a csv file before and after the change using Powershell - ($BeforeAccountChange - Works) $AfterChangeAccount - Does NOT

Tags: powershell

```
$complist = Get-Content "c:\scripts\computers.txt"

foreach($computer in $complist){
    Write-Host "Checking on $computer" -ForegroundColor yellow
    Write-host ""

$pingtest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if($pingtest){
     
       Write-Host($computer + " is online") -ForegroundColor Green
       Invoke-Command -Computername $computer {
                            
            Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "ontapavc"}
       
       $service = Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "name='ontapavc'" 
       $BeforeChangeAccount=$service.StartName 
                     
            Write-Host ""   
       Write-Host "Logon Credentials for " -ForegroundColor cyan -NoNewline;Write-Host $service.DisplayName -NoNewline; Write-Host " prior to Script Change: "-ForegroundColor cyan -NoNewline;Write-Host $service.StartName
           
            Write-Host "" 
            Write-Host "Setting default logon Credentials" -ForegroundColor yellow
            SC.exe CONFIG "ontapavc" obj= Home\Tester password= "Testing"  
            $AfterChangeAccount=$service.StartName
                            
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Setting Recovery Options" -ForegroundColor yellow
            
            SC.exe failure "ontapavc" reset= 60000 actions= restart/60000/restart/60000/reboot/60000
            
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Stopping service " -ForegroundColor yellow -NoNewline; Write-Host $service.name 
            Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "ontapavc"} | Stop-Service -PassThru 
            Write-Host "" 
            Write-Host "Restarting service " -ForegroundColor yellow -NoNewline; Write-Host $service.name
            Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "ontapavc"} | Start-Service -PassThru  
            Write-Host "" 
            Write-Host ""    
            Write-Host ""
            
            }
                            
            Write-Host "Logon Credentials for " -ForegroundColor cyan -NoNewline;Write-Host $servicename -NoNewline; Write-Host " after Change:"-ForegroundColor cyan -NoNewline;Write-Host $afterchangeaccount

$Sample = Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from win32_service where name='ontapavc'" -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object @{Name = 'Time'; Expression = {(Get-Date -format s)}}, PSComputerName, Name,DisplayName, ServiceName, Status, @{Name = 'Username Prior to Change'; Expression = { ($BeforeChangeAccount = $service.StartName)}}, @{Name = 'Username After Change'; Expression = { ($AfterChangeAccount = $service.StartName)}}
$Sample | Export-Csv -Path c:\Temp\ServiceList_-$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation
           
 }else{
   
    Write-Host $computer "is not reachable" -ForegroundColor red
    Write-host ""
 }
```

}

Comment: in both cases (also beforeChangeAccount) you must not assign the value to a variable: ```$AfterChangeAccount = $service.StartName``` you want that value returned  and displayed as value of the property ```'Username After Change'```. so replace the above with ```$service.StartName```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 variables mentioned live in a remote scope. Therefore, you need to bring them out of your `Invoke-Command` to be referenced in your local scope.

```
$complist = Get-Content "c:\scripts\computers.txt"

foreach($computer in $complist){
    Write-Host "Checking on $computer" -ForegroundColor yellow
    Write-host ""

    $pingtest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($pingtest) {
         
        Write-Host($computer + " is online") -ForegroundColor Green
        Invoke-Command -Computername $computer {
                                
            Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "ontapavc"} | Write-Host
            $service = Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "name='ontapavc'" 
            $BeforeChangeAccount=$service.StartName 
                         
            Write-Host ""   
            Write-Host "Logon Credentials for " -ForegroundColor cyan -NoNewline;Write-Host $service.DisplayName -NoNewline; Write-Host " prior to Script Change: "-ForegroundColor cyan -NoNewline;Write-Host $service.StartName
               
            Write-Host "" 
            Write-Host "Setting default logon Credentials" -ForegroundColor yellow
            SC.exe CONFIG "ontapavc" obj= Home\Tester password= "Testing"  
            $AfterChangeAccount=$service.StartName
                                
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Setting Recovery Options" -ForegroundColor yellow
                
            SC.exe failure "ontapavc" reset= 60000 actions= restart/60000/restart/60000/reboot/60000
                
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Stopping service " -ForegroundColor yellow -NoNewline; Write-Host $service.name 
            Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "ontapavc"} | Stop-Service -PassThru | Write-Host
            Write-Host "" 
            Write-Host "Restarting service " -ForegroundColor yellow -NoNewline; Write-Host $service.name
            Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "ontapavc"} | Start-Service -PassThru | Write-Host
            Write-Host "" 
            Write-Host ""    
            Write-Host ""

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Before = $BeforeChangeAccount
                After  = $AfterChangeAccount
            }
                
        } | Set-Variable changes
                                
        Write-Host "Logon Credentials for " -ForegroundColor cyan -NoNewline;Write-Host $servicename -NoNewline; Write-Host " after Change:"-ForegroundColor cyan -NoNewline;Write-Host $afterchangeaccount

        $Sample = Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from win32_service where name='ontapavc'" -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object @{Name = 'Time'; Expression = {(Get-Date -format s)}}, PSComputerName, Name,DisplayName, ServiceName, Status, @{Name = 'Username Prior to Change'; Expression = { $changes.Before}}, @{Name = 'Username After Change'; Expression = { $changes.After}}
        $Sample | Export-Csv -Path c:\Temp\ServiceList_-$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation
               
     }else{
       
        Write-Host $computer "is not reachable" -ForegroundColor red
        Write-host ""
     }
}
```

By not polluting the pipeline, you should be able to create a **pscustomobject** to hold the two outputs you're looking for.

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Before = $BeforeChangeAccount
    After  = $AfterChangeAccount
}
```

Now you can save to a variable to reference later on in your calculated properties since `$changes` now holds a **before** and **after** property.

Comment: I tried the code above and everything works EXCEPT the $changes.Before and Changes.After in the $Sample at the end both display the same user. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @InterestedInPowerShell, ahh, I see. Change the variable to `$AfterChangeAccount = (Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "name='ontapavc'").StartName`. You have to query for the new start name since `$service` holds the old one